# Traduction of “rationale”

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

What would be the best French translation for "rationale", in the sense given on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rationale) (that doesn't have any foreign language equivalent) ? At first I'd think "motivations" or "choix techniques" but I'm really not sure. I'm a French native, but that term has always puzzled me...

The meaning is well described on the page, I'll just add that it is frequently used for software design, to describe the initial choices that led to some design.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I was also thinking about "Motivation des choix techniques" but it is far less concise than in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with chilladx, especially the sense of "justification," and to connect it to "design rationale" I've seen "dossier de justification de conception" on [job descriptions](http://www.handicap-job.com/recherche/detail/oid/1613281/ingenieur-architecte-systemes-h-f.html) and resumes.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the context, but I'd use 'la raison', 'les justifications' or 'la logique'.

Comment: "la logique" est un bon choix car cela englobe l'idée de "raison", de "raisons" et de "justification".

Comment: "le raisonnement" is also used interchangeably with "la logique", especially in scientific contexts

Comment: "la raison derrière quelque chose / un choix" me semble particulièrement approprié